# Creating a DEB with only postinst and postrm but no binary content

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb, debian

I am trying to create a deb package with a control file that is basically a list of  `Depends` and a `postinst` and a `prerm` script. In other words, there are no binary files to be deployed as part of this deb package installation.

When I do my usual `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b`, I get the following output (I have `DH_VERBOSE=1` set in my rules file

```
 dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=binary
dpkg-genbuildinfo: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; .buildinfo is meaningless
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-genbuildinfo --build=binary subprocess returned exit status 25
Makefile:15: recipe for target 'deb' failed
```

What is the correct way to create such a debian package?

Comment: [Here is one good example](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-meta) for the ubuntu-minimal, ubuntu-standard, and ubuntu-desktop metapackages. Note that these metapackages lack postinst and prerm scripts. The list of dependencies is simply inserted into the control file at build time...which you can do manually instead of mucking with dpkg-buildpackage if you wish.